# bluetooth enable discoverable intent returns No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, android-bluetooth

When I start my main activity, it has a function that enables bluetooth discovery after checking if bluetooth is on. I call the intent from the bluetooth adapter based on this [android bluetooth tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#FindingDevices) on debug, logcat shows the error:

```
 Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE (has extras) }
```

I have tried to add an intent filter shown below in the manifest, however that has not stopped the app from crashing here.

I have the manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.waimondfung.a2dpspeaker">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:banner="@drawable/app_icon_your_company"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Leanback">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="=android.bluetooth.adapter.action.REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".discoveryActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_discovery">
    </activity>
</application>
```

for the following code:

```
public void enableDiscovery() {
    Intent discoverableIntent =
            new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 300);
    startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_DISCOVERY);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you decided to `startActivityForResult`, do you handle the result in overriden method `onResult`? If yes, try with just `startActivity`. If you want to handle discovery change, register `BroadcastReceiver` for `BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED` action. Registering process is described [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices).